# Shiny DataTable Callback

Tags: javascript, r, datatable, shiny

I am a little bit of a javascript novice so I am having trouble getting a function in DataTables callback option to work.

In this small example, I want to write a javascript function so that when a user selects a row in the `mtcars` datatable, if the value of MPG is greater than 20, for their to be an alert that says "Good for you!". It is similar to [this](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html), but that example doesn't use `shiny`. Here is what I tried:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$one <- DT::renderDataTable(mtcars,options=list(callback=DT::JS(
      'function(table) {
      table.on("click.dt","tr", function() {
      var data=table.row(this).data();
      if (parseFloat(data[0]>20.0))      
        alert("Good for you!");
      });}'    
      )))
}

ui <- fluidPage(mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput("one")))
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Selecting rows with MPG greater than 20 does not produce the alert like I want. I feel like I may be fundamentally misunderstanding how the javascript works int he callback option. Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need the body of the `callback` function in the `callback` argument of `renderDataTable` (you don't need `options` here:

```
    server <- function(input, output) {
        output$one <- DT::renderDataTable(mtcars,callback=JS(
                'table.on("click.dt","tr", function() {
                var data=table.row(this).data();
                if (parseFloat(data[1])>20.0)      
                 alert("Good for you!");
})'    
      ))
}
```

Your `parseFloat` was also around the whole `if` condition, and `data[0]` is the name of the cars, `data[1]` will be the mpg.

You can troubleshoot this by using developer tools and `console.log` in your javascript to print to the console. You could for example add `console.log(data)` before your `if` and check what it looks like.